# Error: Main method not found in class. please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

I am learning code and am trying to write code that will check if a word is a palindrome. When I try to run the code in intelliJ I get this error in the title. Here is my code.

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static boolean istPalindrom ( char[] word){
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = word.length - 1;
        while (i2 > i1) {
            if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
                return false;
            }
            ++i1;
            --i2;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did the error tell you? Write a main method.

Comment: See this post https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method

Comment: Before learning code , learn language's syntax and semantics.